# Is it divergent? $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{n!^{3}}{(3n)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

Could you help me with this limit?
$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{n!^{3}}{(3n)!}$ 
I know that it is divergent. But I don't know to which functions to compare.

Comment: I don't see how it doesn't converge to $0$.

Comment: converges.   Reciprocal of a multinomial coefficient that is growing, this shrinks

Comment: Huh??? Cripes. WolframAlpha agrees. Zero. But HOW?? So much for the "gut" in my other comment....

Comment: To no one's surprise, Derive 5 also agrees. It's not even close to being large EVER. First term's 1/6 and it's all quickly downhill from there. But somebody please help me see something intuitive that tell's me 0. Like @KennyLau. Anyway, I wouldn't delete  my "gut" and "huh??" comments, even if I could.

Comment: @DSlomer64 how I see it intuitively: $\frac{n!^3}{(3n)!}$ = $\frac{n(n-1)\cdots1 \cdot n(n-1)\cdots1 \cdot n(n-1)\cdots1}{(3n)(3n-1)\cdots(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)\cdots(n+1)n(n-1)\cdots1}$ = $\frac{n(n-1)\cdots1\cdot n(n-1)\cdots1}{(3n)(3n-1)\cdots(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)\cdots(n+1)}$ = $\frac13 \cdot \frac13 \cdots \frac12 \cdot \frac12 \cdots 1 \to 0$

Comment: Thanks, Kenny. Didn't mean to put you on the spot. (I guess I accidentally typed your name, then!) I'm still studying all of the Answers. Yours could be an Answer...Yes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HInt :Use test ratio $$a_n=\frac{n!^{3}}{(3n)!}\\\to 
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\frac{(n+1)!^{3}}{(3n+3)!}}{\frac{n!^{3}}{(3n)!}}=\\\frac{(n+1)!^3}{n!^3}.\frac{(3n)!}{(3n+3)!}=\\
\frac{(n)!^3(n+1)^3}{n!^3}.\frac{(3n)!}{(3n)!(3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3)}=\\
\frac{(n+1)^3}{1}.\frac{1}{(3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3)}=\\
\frac{n^3+..}{27n^3+...}\to \frac{1}{27} <1$$this mean 
$$a_{n+2} <\frac{1}{27}a_{n+1}<\frac{1}{27^2}a_{n}<\frac{1}{27^3}a_{n-1}<...\\so \\\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!^{3}}{(3n)!} \to 0$$

Comment: The gut tells you it's probably a "tie" in racing to infinity if there's no exponent in the numerator. But there is. So it gets humongous soon enough.

Comment: It is no longer a hint ...

Comment: Yeah.......... Well...... Gut isn't a good way to do math. You sure need symbol manipulation..... But, boy... counterintuitive or *what*? Danged good question! Limit at 0 is interesting.

Comment: @Khosrotash I used ratio 's criterion too +1

Comment: "You sure need symbol manipulation..."  Yeah, to PROVE it. But look at (even mentally compute) n(3) and d(3) where n and d are numerator and denominator and you begin to get it: 216/362800. Proves nothing, not even to gut, but now gut's in knots because of the counter-intuitiveness of it all. "For which values of c do (n!)^3/(c n)!  and (n!)^c/(c n)!  converge and to what?" is probably obvious but it showed me the significance of the 3 in the original sequence.

Comment: Too bad whoever "thumbs-upped" me can't take it back. Sorry, dude. (I was so happy .... for about 3 minutes....)

Answer (score 3):

No, because it's $$\large\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\binom{3n}{n,n,n}}.$$

Comment: Why are you answering "yes" to "is it divergent"?

Comment: The phrasing is confusing. "Yes, of course" suggests it diverges, since that's what the OP asked. But yes, of course it converges (to zero).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom it converges to $0$.

Comment: "Divergent to zero"? Is that a thing now?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg the phrase "divergent to zero" is fine in the context infinite products, but this is the first time I'm hearing it in the context of limits of sequences/functions.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom My English is very bad. I fixed. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I have no reason to believe that your English is less than perfect, even with the unusual usage of "divergent".  You're welcome.

Comment: Well it diverges to zero is a nice expression for expressing convergence... Next time I will use it to remember Michael's expression

Comment: You have to PROVE $\binom{3n}{n,n,n}\to\infty$, not just to assert it.

Comment: @Hans What do you mean?

Comment: I retyped my last comment. I am saying you have not proved it.

Comment: @Hans it's coefficient before $x^ny^nz^n$ in $(x+y+z)^{3n}$. I think it's obvious that it $\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: Yes, it is the coefficient and it is intuitive, but that is NO proof. I think you know that, of all people.